# Tkinter Toplevel gets poped up when I run the code

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want the popup to appear after clicking the button but it gets popped up while opening the app
Here is the command for popup

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def add_caster():
    global firstname,lastname
    add_cd= tk.Toplevel(cpdata)
    add_cd.overrideredirect(True)
    firstname="hello again"
    lastname="welcome"
    add_cdl_offsetx, toplevel_offsety = cpdata.winfo_x() + cpdata.winfo_width(), cpdata.winfo_y()
    padx = 0  # the padding you need.
    pady = 0
    add_cd.geometry(f"+{add_cdl_offsetx + padx}+{toplevel_offsety + pady}")
    return(firstname,lastname)
def create_table():
    add_caster()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS autos;") # use this line only if you want to overwrite existing table
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autos ('models' TEXT, 'year' DATE);")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES (?, ?);", (firstname, lastname))
   # cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES ('Sample Data', 1965);")
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
def combo_values_input():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('vehicles.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = cur.execute('SELECT models FROM autos')
    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
    return data
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
cpdata = tk.Tk()
cpdata.title('Testing Tkinter Combobox with Sqlite')
create_table()
combo = ttk.Combobox(cpdata, width=50, height=20)
combo.grid()
combo.insert(0,'Select the caster')
combo.configure(state='readonly')
combo['values'] = combo_values_input()
btn_addcc= tk.Button(cpdata,command=add_caster).grid(row=1,column=10)
cpdata.mainloop()
```

Can anybody help me in this.The code works fine but the popup behaves abnormally

Comment: Based on the posted code, the mentioned issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @acw1668 kindly see the code I have updated the code

Comment: You have called `add_caster()` inside `create_table()`.

Comment: That is bacause i want to take values of ```firstname``` and ```lastname``` without add_caster command it throws an error saying firstname is not defined. If I remove that line the line ```cur.execute("INSERT INTO autos VALUES (?, ?);", (firstname, lastname))``` will throw an error. Is there any other way to get rid of this problem? Kindly suggest.

Comment: I don't understand why you insert record into the table inside `create_table()` since the name of the function suggests it is used to *create table*.  You need to think again yourself when to insert new record into the table instead.  Also the columns of `autos` table are `models` and `year`, so why do you use `firstname` and `lastname`?

Comment: The word firstname and lastname has no meaning model represents first name and year represents last name. they are variables which will come as an output(let c=a+b, i have to use c and I want to insert c into database) . Can It be done by using global variables? Please help. I am stuck here for last two days